# Replace only the first specific occurrence

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to replace the spaces that are only in parentheses. My code changes all the spaces in the string & I don't know why. I wrote the code like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    line = scanner.nextLine();
    for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
        if (line.charAt(i)=='('){
            while (line.charAt(i)!=')'){
                i++;
                if(line.charAt(i)==' '){
                    line=line.replaceFirst(" ", "-space-");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend ditching that whole mess and going with a regex.

Comment: You're also calling `line=line.replaceFirst(" ", "-space-");`. Line is never modified once you're in the loop, so you're going to replace the first space in the entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replaced one line: Only the spaces in the parantheses are changed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    line = scanner.nextLine();
    for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
        if (line.charAt(i)=='('){
            while (line.charAt(i)!=')'){
                i++;
                if(line.charAt(i)==' '){
                    // changed
                    line = line.substring(0, i) + "-space-" + line.substring(i+1, line.length());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(line);     
    scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter something");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        line = scanner.nextLine();

        for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++) {
            if (line.charAt(i)=='(') {
                while (line.charAt(i)!=')') {
                    if(line.charAt(i)==' ') {
                        line=line.replaceFirst(" ", "-space-");
                        break; //leave while
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
            break; //leave for loop
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Check the output [image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your logic, you are using the method replaceFirst in the line, which "Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement." instead of just consume the spaces and insert '-space'.

It would be better to use regexp as suggested but if you want to go in this way,try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    line = scanner.nextLine();
    int begin;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if (line.charAt(i) == '(') {
            i++;
            begin = i;
            while (line.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                i++;
            }
            if (line.charAt(i) == ')') {
                line = line.substring(0, begin) + 
                        "-space-" + line.substring(i, line.length());
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

With regexp you can do something like:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String line = "asdfsadf (       )   (   adsf)  asdf()asdfasdf( )  (  asdf  (     )";
    String line1 = line.replaceFirst("(\\(\\s+\\))", "(-space-)");
    String line2 = line.replaceAll("(\\(\\s+\\))", "(-space-)");

    System.out.println(line);
    System.out.println(line1);
    System.out.println(line2);
  }
```

Which give you as output:

```
asdfsadf (       )   (   adsf)  asdf()asdfasdf( )  (  asdf  (     )
asdfsadf (-space-)   (   adsf)  asdf()asdfasdf( )  (  asdf  (     )
asdfsadf (-space-)   (   adsf)  asdf()asdfasdf(-space-)  (  asdf  (-space-)
```

Depending on your needs you can modify it.

Comment: yeah.. i got why my code didn't work.. but my question is actually is there something like replaceFirst that instead of changing the first thing that we want, or instead of replace that changes everything, it changes something in a specific  place in a string for once.. ??

Comment: Check the following example using regexp with replaceFirst and replaceAll